# HTML Form Mutli Select array not working

Tags: php, html, arrays, multi-select

I have a simple form with multi select like this

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="submitted_category[]" >
<option value="test">test</option>
<option value="tests">tests</option>
<option value="testing">testing</option>
</select>
```

But when I print_r the array it just prints it as "Array"

Here's the php

```
$submitted_category = $_POST['submitted_category']; 

if(isset($submitted_category)){
print_r($submitted_category);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I get "A" no mater how many items I set

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Print the element you wish to return.  Example:

```
print_r($submitted[1]);  // print element at position 1
```

or:

```
print_r($submitted[0]);  //index of array.
```

Try:

```
var_dump($submitted);
```

as well.

Comment: That means you selected `tests` and it found an array with one value of `string(5)` (5 characters)

Comment: thank you chitowns.  So how do I count the number of values in the array is it count($submitted_categories)

Comment: I think array_count_values($submitted_category); might work.  print_r(array_count_values($submitted_category)); if you want to print it to the screen.

Comment: i tried var_dump again and i tried all 3 selections and it always said string(5) Array

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($submitted_category[0]);
```

You set your select to be an array of values, so you need to choose which Index you want to print out

Something like this as well may help you see all of the values if you are using more than one select

```
foreach($submitted_category as $value)
{
   print_r($value);
}
```